# Using aws sdk for javascript to write condition expressoins in DynamoDB when a new attribute is greater than the origin attribute

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update an item in DynamoDB when a new attribute is greater than the origin one.

for example, a sample dynamodb structure given below

```
id(primary key)  value   count
---------------  -----   -----
a                1       10
b                2       10

-------------------------------------------
// When input this item, I wish not to update
-------------------------------------------
a                5       9 (9 is smaller than 10)

-------------------------------------------
// When input this item, I wish to update
-------------------------------------------
b                5       15 (15 is greater than 10)
```

Here is my code:

```
const DynamoDB = require('aws-sdk').DynamoDB;
const db = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const TableName = "sample_table";

function update(id, value, count)
{
    return db.update({
        TableName,
        Key: { 
            id
        },
        UpdateExpression: "SET #value = :value, #count = :count",
        ConditionExpression: "#count > :count",
        ExpressionAttributeNames:
        {
            "#value": "value",
            "#count": "count"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues:
        {
            ":value": value,
            ":count": count
        }
    }).promise();
}
update("a", 5, 9);
update("b", 5, 15);
```

But after I run this code, it will throw error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConditionalCheckFailedException: The
>   conditional request failed

How to use ConditionExpression parameter to meet my need, how can I fixed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected. Because the first update - `update("a", 5, 9)` will be rejected as it fails to satisfy your condition. DynamoDB `rejects` the promise if Conditional Expressions fails. You should handle this in your code.

Maybe something like:

```
update('a', 5, 9)
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
})
.catch((err) => {
    if (err.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
        return 'Ok I know this';
    }
    throw err;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally found the problem: 
If the condition expression evaluates to false, DynamoDB returns the following error message: The conditional request failed